# Design an algorithm to check whether k integers add up to x in the given set

Tags: algorithm

Given an set of n integers and an integer x. Can you design an algorithm to check whether k integers add up to x in the given set?
The complexity should be O(n^(k-1) * logn)

Comment: Questions usually have at least one question mark in them.

Comment: @TimCooper - well they are in a hurry, they are in an interview right now posting this on their iPhone!

Comment: Try `Array`'s `permutation` function.

Comment: Perhaps he can't even copy his homework question properly, let alone get others to answer it...

Comment: Why do you need this? Is this homework? Its ok to ask for help in homework, but please make it clear if it is.

Answer (score 3):

1. Sort the array
2. Take combinations of k numbers (all n^(k-1) of them)
3. For each combination check if x-sum(combination) is in the array (binary search, O(log(n)).

Final complexity: O(n^(k-1) * logn)

You can also do it in O( n^(k/2) log(n) ) if you have enough space ( n^(k/2) length array.

Calculating sum is O(1), because you can reuse the computation you made for the previous combination. If you have computed (a+b+c+d), (a+b+c+e) = (a+b+c+d) -d +e.

Comment: And how do we find `sum(combination)`? Wouldn't that take `O(n)` time raising the complexity to `O(n^(k-1) * n)`? Also, I believe in step 2, you mean "... of k-1 number ...".

Comment: Lastly, are you sure there are `n^(k-1)` combinations? I believe there are n choose k of them and I don't see how they're equal.

Comment: @quasiverse... nCk-1 is < n*(n-1)... (n-k) < O(n^k-1)... so he is right